# Creating new feature class based on x- and y- coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, feature-class

I need to create a new feature class with four different points on it from various x- and y- coordinates.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Step-by-step instructions would be helpful.

I should also mention that I have to use ArcGIS 10.1. This is for a class project.

Comment: Use QGIS, add delimited text layer, point it to the X and Y fields, make sure it draws correctly, save it as a shapefile.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to create a feature class using any method? Are your x,y values on a piece of paper, in a spreadsheet, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Use ArcCatalog to create your point feature class.  And be sure you are using the correct CRS.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_feature_classes

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//005s0000001v000000

Then go to ArcGIS Desktop, and either:

1. Start an edit session and manually drop the points.

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//001t00000019000000.htm

2. put the point locations (ie addresses, xy) in a excel spreadsheet and geocode the points

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/geocoding-tutorial.pdf

voila! all done

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to go about it:

1. Create an Excel spreadsheet specifying the coordinates. Don't create an ID field - ArcMap will not recognize it coming from an Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

2. Select File > Add Data > Add XY Data. Choose your spreadsheet and X and Y fields, select the proper coordinate system and confirm.

[image]

3. Since your new layer does not have an ID field, in order to edit, perform relates, or make selections on the map, you will have to now export the new layer. Export by right clicking the layer, selecting Data > Export Data and then choosing a location for the new feature class.

[image]